# I am getting error KeyError: 'duration' when it exists

Tags: python, pandas

The following code returns error

```
KeyError: 'duration'


for i in range(0, 3): 
     exam_df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(i,(exam_df['Duration '])[i])
exam_df['grade'] = exam_df['Grade'].astype(np.int64)
exam_df.plot.scatter(x='duration', y='grade')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.
The code you posted is not sufficient to reproduce the error: "pd" is not defined.  Also include the entire error message, including stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you misspelled the key 'duration', try to change:

```
exam_df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(i,(exam_df['Duration '])[i])
```

With:

```
exam_df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(i,(exam_df['duration'])[i])
```